# Prevent the user with session from entering the URL in browser and access the data in Python Django Application

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a Python Django web application.
In Get method how to prevent the user from entering url and access the Data.
How do i know weather the url accessed by Code or Browser.
I tried with sessionid in Cookie, But if session exist's it allow to access the data.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only wanting them to be able to access certain pages once logged in you can use

```
@login_required
```

above the def in Views.

eg:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'enrolment/index.html')
```

If you're looking for a more general solution I'm not sure sorry

Answer (score 0):

To detect if request is from browser, you can check HTTP_USER_AGENT header

`request.META.get("HTTP_USER_AGENT")`

Answer (score 0):

I achieve it by 
if 'HTTP_REFERER' not in request.META:

it not exist's when hit directly from browser url.